# How to check for a class present on an element with Symfony DOMcrawler?

Tags: php, domcrawler, symphony-cms

I have a `$foo` which is an instance of `Crawler` and `$foo->outerHtml()` starts with `<div class="brick brick--type--test brick--id--1`. I am writing a test and I'd like to assert `brick--id--1` is indeed present as a class. How could I do this? (`preg_match()` on `$foo->outerHtml()` invokes Cthulhu, I'd rather not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Evaluate an XPATH expression against the nodes](https://replit.com/@oluwafemisule/Symfony-Domcrawler#main.php) to check whether they [contain the CSS class](https://devhints.io/xpath).

```php
<?php

require('vendor/autoload.php');
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$html = <<<'HTML'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="brick brick--type--test brick--id--1">Hello</div>
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

$crawler = new Crawler($html);

$foo = $crawler->filter('body > div');
$class = 'brick--id--1';
$expr = "contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' $class ')";
$result = $foo->evaluate($expr);
var_dump($result);
// array(1) {
//   [0]=>
//   bool(true)
// }
var_dump(array_sum($result) !== 0);
// bool(true)
```

Comment: Thanks. Does the expression need to be this complicated? What does `normalize-space()` buy us? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space says "The normalize-space function strips leading and trailing white-space from a string, replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space, and returns the resulting string." and I do not see that necessary?

Comment: That's correct what the documentation says. We normalize tabs and newline characters to spaces as well so that we can match them against the '[:space:][classname][:space]' pattern.

Answer (score -1):

```
$crawler->matches('.brick--id--1');
```

Comment: Hello, please add any sort of information about your code instead of just submitting a line and leaving it without any context.

Comment: The question is "How to check for a class present on an element with Symfony DOMcrawler?"

The answer is 

`$crawler->matches('.brick--id--1');`